# Illustrator dropshadow with some distance

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, drop-shadow

I am struggling to find an easy option for this:

[image]

Which would be like a dropshadow with a distance between my path and the shadow.

These are just sloppy example to show you what I mean but this is how I created the one above:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add multiple strokes via the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]
<sub>(click the image to see it larger)</sub>

- Start with the object
- Add a thicker, white stroke under the object
- add a "shadow" colored stroke under the white stroke.
- Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` from the menu with the last stroke highlighted in the **Appearance Panel**
- Adjust the `Vertical` option in the `Move` section to move the stroke away from the object.

The white stroke will hide or cover up  the underlying "shadow" stroke.

If you then want to individually alter the everything, or get rid of the white stroke, you can choose `Object > Expand Appearance` and you will have individual objects for each stroke....

[image]

You can then click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel** to remove any overlapping areas and create a flat collection of individual shapes based upon what is visible.

Then delete the white areas and you are left with the original shape, and individual pieces for the offset shadow:

[image]